# Condition for some column in foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, constraints

There is table A with columns (Id, BId). BId is foreign key to table B. B has columns (Id, Type).

```
CREATE TABLE [A] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [PK_A_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [BId] INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [FK_A_B] REFERENCES [B](Id) 
)
GO
CREATE TABLE [B] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [PK_B_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Type] INT NOT NULL 
)
GO
```

So, it is very simple scheme, but I want to add condition for foreign keys like "type should be 0". It should be something like

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_A_B] REFERENCES [B](Id) WHERE [B].[Type] = 0
```

How to use UNIQUE keyword or smth else correctly to realize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not a task for FOREIGN KEY. In FK you can't specify additional conditions on a target table. If you have such need, usually it means that your DB is not normalized. It looks like table [B] stores several data entities in one table, and Type column determines what entity it is. If you broke normalization rules, declarative integrity means like FK don't work for you. From now on you have to control integrity on your own. You can do this in application logic or create triggers (procedural integrity). In any case there will be no foreign key constraint in DB.

Comment: I think you're right, it would be better to normalize db ad do something with unique constraint

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if this could be done using a filtered unique index.  But, SQL Server doesn't allow that.  So here is another idea:

Start by defining a (redundant) unique constraint on:

```
CREATE TABLE [B] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT [PK_B_Id] PRIMARY KEY,
    [Type] INT NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (ID, Type)
)
GO
```

Now, I don't think you can define the constraint as:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_A_B] (ID, 0) REFERENCES [B](Id, Type)
```

But, I think you can trick it by doing:

```
_Type as 0,
CONSTRAINT [FK_A_B] (ID, _Type) REFERENCES [B](Id, Type)
```

That is, add a computed column and use that for the constraint.